# Why did drop down list cannot display value in browser when variable still keeps correct value after exception?

Tags: angularjs, frontend

My drop down list cannot display selected value for those correct and existing records after exception. I wonder if anyone can give me a hint about direction.

In our team's application, the front end is written in AngularJS. When user wants to add a new record and does not input a mandatory value for a field, he will encounter an exception due to a validation in back end written in Java.

Here is some code:

```
function save() {
    vm.saving = true;
    convertReferenceIdsToNum(vm.waivers);
    waiversService.post(vm.waivers).then(function (response) {
        if (response.importance.toLowerCase() !== 'failure') {
            messagesService.logSuccess("Waivers Updated", "Waivers Updated", null);
            initialize();
        }
        vm.saving = false;
    }).catch(function () {
        vm.saving = false;
    });
}
```

I expect that if the user input is invalid, the screen will return to original GUI that when user input, and those records that have exist should be displayed correctly.

I found my html code was like this for an existing record for vm.waivers, and none of value is selected:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="8260.3B" value="string:5">8260.3B</option>
```

while I expect like this:

```
<option value="" class=""></option>
<option label="8260.3B" value="string:5" selected="selected">8260.3B</option>
```

and I found The if statement ( if (response.importance.toLowerCase() !== 'failure')) was never executed as exception directly jump to catch clause. vm.waiver keeps correct value for all items.

Comment: If you want a failed attempt to "restore" the screen to the user entry prior to attempting the input, then you should copy the `vm.waiver` to a new object prior to converting/processing it.  Or save the current to `vm.preSaveWaiver` and then reset the `vm.waiver` to that in the catch block.

Comment: Are you using `ng-repeat` or `ng-options` to generate the options list? What does the code use for the `ng-model`?

Comment: Yes,  georgeawg, the existing code is using ng-repeat to generate multiple records on GUI. The item.code is used for ng-model. and I also have a ng-change function to set another associated record's field value based on selected item.code on the drop down list.

Comment: to  kendavidson:  Thank you for your suggestion. I did the same thing. however, Chrome browser cannot re-render my html code correctly. Only after I enforce to reload those drop down list again like what it did to initialize, the page is rendered correctly. But I have to reload all of things again. Is there anyway that I can enforce to re-render the page without reload every thing?